# if $\sum_{j=1}^n k_j =S $ what is the minimum of $\prod_{j=1}^n k_j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

if $$\sum_{j=1}^n k_j =S $$ what is the minimum for $$\prod_{j=1}^n k_j$$
where S,n are natural numbers and $1 \le k_j \le p_j$ ($p_j$ are primes)

I try to first full the capacity of $k_j$ that has smaller boundaries which here is $k_1$ then if there be any reminder we put it in the $k_2$ then if still there be any reminder we continue to putt them in $k_j$ with smaller $j$ until there be no more S to put in our variable and the rest of $k_j$ will be $1$ .

Is this a good approach ?
If yes ,   how we can formalizing this algorithm ?

**edit:** I tried some example and I find out that this algorithm or any other like this does not always give us the minimum of the products .

what should we do to find minimum of products ?!

Comment: You'd always want to arrange the $p_j$ in decreasing order, so that you're stuffing the maximum at the start. (In fact, you can relax the constraint that $p_j$ are primes, to just natural numbers.) A smoothing argument works to formalize the algorithm.

Comment: can you please explain with more details ? how we can relax the constraint to just natural number ?@CalvinLin

Comment: Let $p_j$ be natural numbers in decreasing order. Suppose we have an arrangement that gives the maximum, and there is a $i < j$ with $k_i < p_i $ and $k_j > 1$. Then show that $(k_i + 1)(k_j - 1 ) > k_ik_j$, which contradicts the assumption that we have a maximum. Thus, at the max, we must have some I where for $ i  < I, k_i  = p_i$ and for $i > I, k_i = 1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin but what about the minimum ?!

Comment: Oh sry typo. Suppose that's our minimum, then show that $(k_i + 1)(k_j -1 ) < k_i k_j$, so contradiction.